# Overriding swift protocol extension

Tags: swift, dispatch

I've got a protocol with a default implementation like so

```
public protocol SettingsIdentifier {
    var key: String { get }
    var prefix: String { get }
    var defaults: DefaultsProtocol { get }
}
```

and a default implementation

```
public extension SettingsIdentifier where Self: RawRepresentable, Self.RawValue == String {
    var key: String { return prefix + rawValue }
    var prefix: String { return "" }
    var defaults: DefaultsProtocol { return UserDefaults.standard as DefaultsProtocol }
}
```

Goal is to override var defaults in Unittesting and providing a mock here. So for SomeDefaults

```
enum SomeDefaults: String, SettingsIdentifier {
   case preconditionFulfilled
   var prefix: String { return "Prefix." }
}
```

I like to provide an extension like

```
extension SomeDefaults {
   var defaults: DefaultsProtocol { return UserDefaultsMock }
}
```

But the override only gets called when I have it defined in the same file as the enum.

Is this somehow related to the swift dispatch behavior?

Comment: from Apple's Swift book: _"Extensions can add new functionality to a type, but they cannot override existing functionality."_ ([reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Extensions.html))

Comment: Weird. Why is it than working if I have the extension in the same file?